# How to install Screenlets on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install Screenlets on Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) so I can have desktop widgets.

I've tried following guides for previous versions, however they do not work for Ubuntu 23.10. How can I install Screenlets on 23.10?